# php select statement using user input not working

Tags: php

I cannot figure this out. I am trying to get data from the my database after the user enters there username, the `$username` variable passed through to the method I made is taken from the login pages `$_POST` global variable. I realized the code works only when I manually enter the values, I tried to bind the variable but that also did not work for me.

```
public static function pullbyUsername($username,$table,$object){
    $sql = "";
    if(is_numeric($username == true)){
        $sql = "SELECT {$object} FROM {$table} WHERE pollId = '{$username}'";
    }
    else{
        $sql = "SELECT {$object} FROM {$table} WHERE username = '{$username}'";
    }
    if($sql != ""){
        try{
            $pdo = new PDO(includes::get('mysql/host'),includes::get('mysql       /username'),includes::get('mysql/password'));

            $result =$pdo->query($sql);
            $rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            return $rows[0][$object];
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) {
            die($ex->getMessage());  
        }
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

I tried this code and it is also not working

```
public static function pulbyUsername($username,$table,$object){
    $sql = "";
    if(is_numeric($username) == true){
      $sql = "SELECT {$object} FROM {$table} WHERE pollId = ':username}'";
    }
    else{
      $sql = "SELECT {$object} FROM {$table} WHERE username = ':username'";
    }
        try{
       $pdo = new PDO(includes::get('mysql/host'),includes::get('mysql/username'),includes::get('mysql/password'));
       $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
       $statement->execute(array('username'=>$username));
       $result = $statement->fetchAll();
       var_dump($result);

       }
```

Comment: echo the `$sql` before execution you got any exception??

Comment: You're currently creating a new database connection _for every unique query_. That means you're closing the connection, connecting again, closing the connection, connecting again etc. Please use a factory pattern to reuse your DB connection. Also, your code is open to SQL injection - use prepared statements and bind your variables as you'd otherwise have issues with usernames with special characters in them (eg `Mc'Fly`). You haven't shown us how you bound the variables, nor explained why it "did not work".

Comment: `if(is_numeric($username == true)){` should be `if(is_numeric($username) == true){`

Comment: and `if($sql != ""){` can be removed. `$sql` will never be empty.

Comment: What is $object argument?

Answer (score 0):

```
 function pulbyUsername($username,$table,$object){
    //$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=wp_db;host=localhost', 'root', '');
    $connStr = 'mysql:dbname=wp_db;host=localhost'; 
    $pdo = new PDO($connStr,'root','');  
    $sql = "";
    if(is_numeric($username) == true){
      $sql = "SELECT ".implode(",", $object)."FROM {$table} WHERE pollId = ':username'";
      //echo $sql;
    }
    else{
      $sql = "SELECT " .implode(",", $object)." FROM {$table} WHERE user_login = '{$username}'";
      //echo $sql;
    }

       //$pdo = new PDO(includes::get('mysql/host'),includes::get('mysql/username'),includes::get('mysql/password'));
       $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute(array('username'=>$username));
       $result = $statement->fetchAll();
       var_dump($result);
       //print_r($result);

 }
 $image_exts = array('ID','user_email');
 pulbyUsername('admin','wp_users',$image_exts);
```

Comment: thanks but it is still not working, I debugged it and for some reason it is returning an empty value, everything else seems fine it just does not retrieve any data

Comment: I forget to add changes for number

Comment: I am trying to pass username as a user input value

Comment: can you test it on localhost.

Comment: its on my localhost, no error $result is just empty

Comment: please create new file in htdocs and paste my code and run.$result never empty because $sql return 1

Comment: Yes i tried that it is still return nothing I dont get how, it does work if i manually write in the $username argument ex. 'user1' but it does not work is i use a variable $user = "user1" for example

Comment: I figured out that the works fine its when I retrieve some data from the $_Post and assign it to a variable only then it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, Vasim Vanzara had it right, however there was white space so I trimed and it works thank you